# Angular ngGrid Tree Control: Make a round trip on group expand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to use `ngGrid` to make somewhat of a "tree-control" which I can build dynamically by calling API's. `ngGrid` allows for grouping on rows, yet the nature of it requires that all rows be present at the beginning. This is unfortunate for the fact that an API to pull back all generation data for a File Integrity Monitoring system would be insanely slow and stupid. Instead, I wish to build the "tree" dynamically on the expansion of each generation.

**I am trying to inject children (`ngRows`) into a group-row (`ngAggregate`) on a callback, yet I do not think that I am calling the correct constructor for the `ngRows` for the fact that the rows are ignored by the control**

Through the use of the `aggregateTemplate` option on the `gridOptions` for `ngGrid`, I have been able to intersept the expansion of a group quite easily.
(maybe not easily, but still)

I've replaced the `ng-click` of the default template:

```
ng-click="row.toggleExpand()"
```

with:

```
ng-click="$parent.$parent.rowExpanded(row)"
```

I know that it's a bit of a hack, but we can get to that later. For now, it gets the job done.

*The way that I discovered how to work my way up the `$scope` to my `rowExpanded` function was by setting a breakpoint in `ngGrid`'s "`row.toggleExpand`" function and calling it from the template as so:*

```
ng-click="row.toggleExpand(this)"
```

Once I retrieve the group I want, I call an API to get the children for said group. I then need to make the return as children of the row. I decided to do this by calling `ngGrid`'s `ngRow` factory:

```
row.children = [];
for(var i = 0; i < childData.length; i++)
{
    row.children[row.children.length] = row.rowFactory.buildEntityRow(childData[i], i);
}
row.toggleExpand();
```

... yet this does not appear to be working. The rows are not showing up after I do the expand! Why won't my rows show up?

[**Here's my current Plunker!**](http://plnkr.co/edit/W2Y3mqADXREIfMVq4YTi?p=preview)

**By the way**

I've placed a debugger statement within the group-expand callback. As long as you have your debugger open, you should catch a breakpoint on the expansion of a group.

***Thanks everybody!***

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, I'm an idiot....

I got this control working, and then realized that it was a total hack, that I could have used the control the way it was meant to be used and it would have worked much better, had much better work-flow, and it would have saved me an entire day of development. If you are wondering how you use the control this way, the answer is that you don't.

I got the stupid thing to work by updating my data structure after the round trip and forcing the grid to refresh, pretty obvious. I had to set the grid options so that groups were always expanded and I had to control the collapser icon logic myself, outside of ngGrid. I never called row.toggleExpand. I also hid any rows with null values by a function call within an ng-if on my rowTemplate. After all that was said and done, I put my foot in my mouth.